# Create a subscription that once captures a valid authState, will stop "polling"

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Is it possible to create a subscription that attempts to get the user's auth state repeatedly until `user != null`, once this is the case then it stops:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]);
    this.authSubscription = this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        localStorage.setItem('uid', user.uid);
        this.store.dispatch(userActions.getData());
      }
    })
  }
```

The console output is as follows which causes the browser to crash:

[image]

My action is as follows:

```
  @Effect()
  getData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.getData),
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.userService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem('uid')).pipe(
          map(
            (data: IUser) => UserActions.dataReceived({ payload: UserService.parseData(data) })
          )
        );
      }
    )
  );
```

Comment: I don't see any polling here? Is this actual code causing these issues? There must be an issue somewhere else in your code then, because `authState` does not behave like that. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: or rather I mean that if you are not intentionally polling the data, it shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `takeUntil()` operator and `interval()`.

I prefer this solution because of you not triggering request 1 after the other, you give some time in between.

Comment: Thanks, can you post a code example please, and how would it work with unsubscribing from the request once data is retrieved